# Question about PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I'm studying PhoneGap and it seems pretty cool, but I'm curious about something.

In Android, I would create different classes (or Activities) for like different parts of the application. How would this be accomplished in PhoneGap? Create a new HTML document with new CSSS and JS files?

Does the JS and CSS coding need to be in in the HTML document, or can it be made external for each HTML?

I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by different 'classes'. Are you talking about CSS?

You can link to external JS and CSS files ok. One thing to watch out for is that

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

won't work, as the folder containing all your files is not the root! You need to use relative paths like so:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I guess I meant starting a new activity...i believe in java its called creating a nee class, and in android its activity

Comment: @richard what Anthony means is whether we can have in a webapp both index.html and, let's say, map.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't create Android apps in PhoneGap, instead you create HTML/JS apps that run on a number of platforms. PhoneGap apps are more closely related to web apps,

To begin with web apps, are usually build with an MVC structure separating the Model, the View and the Controller aspects of the app. And secondly, the coding is done in Javascript which does not have classes so you do not have to do things the same way you do with C++ or Java.

Typically, web apps have one HTML file, a small number of CSS files often only one, and several JS files. Usually there is one JS file for some kind of JS framework, several for plugins or useful libraries, and then one for the core application that you write.

Comment: You say "typically", so it is possible to have 1+ html files, isn't it? I am worried because I cannot imagine just one html file where I'd place all my app code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using JQuery Mobile, a framework which works very well with Phonegap. Using JQuery Mobile, you only need to use 1 HTML file where you can specify multiple div tags within this file for each screen or activity in your application.

for example, you might have two screens: home and task. To specify the different activities, or pages, you would use:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
<div data-role="page" id="task">
```

The CSS and JavaScript can also be in different files, you just need to include them in the package when you upload it to Phonegap to be compiled.